# Parse error in simple Haskell Fibonacci implementation

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I've tried to make an iterative/tail-recursive version of a function to compute the *n*th number of the Fibonacci sequence, but I'm getting `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)`.  Why is this happening?  The code I'm using:

```
fib n
    | n < 2 = n
    | otherwise = fibhelper 0 1 2 n
    where fibhelper a b curr num
          | curr == num = a + b
          | curr < num = fibhelper b (a+b) (curr+1) num
```

To be clear, I'm trying to understand the error - why it's happening, how it should be corrected - and not trying to implement `fib` efficiently (I understand the popular `zipWith` implementation [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence) already, for instance).

Thanks!

Comment: Thankfully, you received a good answer quickly. Please, if you could, be sure to say where the compiler had placed the error, not just what the error is. Once more, though, congrats on getting a fast, good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guard part has to be indented at least one character relative to the function name.  The following thus works:

```
fib n
    | n < 2 = n
    | otherwise = fibhelper 0 1 2 n
    where fibhelper a b curr num
           | curr == num = a + b  -- moved one character to the left.
           | curr < num = fibhelper b (a+b) (curr+1) num
```

Comment: Aha!  It had to be something like that, but I wasn't sure what.  Thanks for your help!